# Git Revert has conflicts, when resolved it is not Actually Reverting the Changes?

Tags: git

I have identified commit `b67564d` as the problem. Somehow the user managed to have 3 merges before and 3 merges afterwards. Currently the repo looks like this (Bar, Joe and Bar represent different users):

```
Foo: Revert "Fixed Satellite"
...
Joe: Merge branch 'master' of github.com:...... (No Files)
Bar: Merge branch 'master' of github.com:...... (No Files)
Bar: Merge branch 'master' of github.com:...... (2 Files)
Bar: Fixed Satellite                            (5 files: b67564d)
Bar: Merge branch 'master' of github.com:...... (No Files)
Bar: Merge branch 'master' of github.com:...... (No Files)
Bar: Merge branch 'playground'                  (No Files)
```

So I run: `git revert b67564d`

`error: could not revert...
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' and commit result`

So I run: `git mergetool`

So I resolve conflicts (It was a log file that is ignored but keeps finding it's way in)

`git status`

Shows Changes to be committed as the 4 files from b67564d excluding the recently merged log file.

So I run `git revert --continue`

Which gives:

`[master cc8b21b] Revert "Fixed Satellite" 4 files changed`

Now I look at the Supposedly changed files, and it hasn't changed at all.

Output of `git log --graph --oneline` as requested:

```
* cc8b21b Revert "Fixed Satellite"
* fc06865 Revert "Styled accordian on Enterprise edit page but Error displayed if a table is empty"
*   ed07e58 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:x/p-o-2
|\
| * 84fd05e Added scroll bars to accordian panels for mobile responsiveness (too many columns in tables)
| *   010deba Merge branch 'master' of github.com:x/p-o-2
| |\
| | *   bdcc3ae Merge branch 'master' of github.com:x/p-o-2
| | |\
| | * \   e57f0cd Merge branch 'master' of github.com:x/p-o-2
| | |\ \
| | * | | b67564d Fixed Satellite
| | * | |   eaea47a Merge branch 'master' of github.com:x/p-o-2
| | |\ \ \
| | * \ \ \   b3d3f0c Merge branch 'master' of github.com:x/p-o-2
| | |\ \ \ \
```

Comment: Can we see the output of `git log --graph --oneline` instead please?

Comment: ok I've updated with your request

Comment: Thank you. On a side note, your team should consider more rebasing of feature branches on top of `master` instead of just merging `master` in, like what's in your current log graph, in order to make working with commits and branches and merges easier and less confusing.

Comment: When you checked the status of the reverted files after fixing conflicts, did you actually check the diff to verify that they were the ***reverse*** of the changes made in the commit that you were trying to revert?

Comment: Looks like the changes were not in that commit and it was an earlier commit. I can find which commit the change is made as I checkout and test, checkout test until I find the commits where the app breaks. However on this commit there is no changes to the file that is causing the error.

Comment: So you're saying that you reverted the wrong commit? Also, if you're going to hunt down the buggy commit by testing a bunch of revisions, are you using a binary search method, such as `git bisect`?

Comment: Yes It seems I reverted the wrong one, but the buggy commit I found doesn't contain code changes to the particular file that would affect it. but this is a coding problem them and not problem of git. No I'm not using `git bisect` because I don't know what it is, would it be recommended?

Comment: [`git bisect`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) is a git command that automates the process of finding a commit that introduces a bug via binary search. You don't ***need*** to use bisect to do this, you can do it manually, but if you ever wanted to automate the process, this is a tool that you can use. You can also read more about it from [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-5.html#Binary-Search).